# Where can I find Officer Dellk?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On the Citadel, on the Citadel Embassies level, there is a listing on the map for an Officer Dellk. I've looked around the area marked 4 (Embassy Offices), and the entire level and haven't found anyone else to interact with by this name. Is the character there to talk to? What species are they? Any advice on where to find them would be helpful.

[image: Officer Dellk, where are you?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Officer Dellk is the Turian standing in front of the console in a little back area past Udina's office. You can see him here in this video:

You may run into a problem where he doesn't show up at first if you've just gotten the intel from the Specter office. I ran into this issue at first where he wasn't where I was expected. I was able to solve this problem by going back to the Normandy and then returning to the spot on the map, and fortunately he had appeared. Hopefully that will work for you too.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I hadn't ventured back in to that area after all.